# SQLite/SQLite-Bridging.h not found in SQLite.swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I'm using SQLite.swit (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) to develop an app. I was following the Pod installation guide and can get it running on iOS simulator. However, when I try to install the app on my test device, it shows the error

```
/Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods/SQLite.framework/Headers/SQLite.h:9:9: 
error: 'SQLite/SQLite-Bridging.h' file not found
```

Is it my way of configuration incorrect? Anyway ran into the same issue as mine?

Comment: Try this: Go to Build Settings, search for "Defines module" and set it to "YES". Still in Build Settings, search for "Embedded Content contains Swift code" and turn it to "YES". Recompile. Does it work?

Comment: Still the same error. I set both options to Yes in both my App and Pod.

Comment: Don't know anything else, sorry

Answer (score 8):

I initially fixed this by changing the #include line to look like below:

```
#import "SQLite-Bridging.h"
```

I find it weird that I have to make such changes. Digging in deeper, I found what I think as cached files under ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. I clean up the folder related to my project and run `pod update`. That did it for me.

I was on older version of SQLite.swift and when upgrading, I deduce that xcode did not updating some cached files. If you also came from upgrading from older, the above trick may work for you.

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to @maresa's answer, but simplifying it, all I had to do was go to Window > Projects and delete the DerivedData folder info.

[image]

(*Update*: In Xcode 8 this location no longer appears. Supposedly Xcode cleans up Derived Data by itself. If you want to delete it manually you can find the folder yourself by going to Preferences > Locations and clicking the gray arrow by the Derived Data folder. Then delete your project folder.)

Answer (score 1):

There are different instructions for an iOS project. Did you try these steps?

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#frameworkless-targets

Comment: @firstprayer what do you mean with "changing the subproject"?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by cleaning the project folder.You can try to hold option ,then click Product -> Clean build folder.