# How to use Sqlite3 with XCode 8.1 and swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, sqlite

Actually, I'm using **SQLite.swift** wrapper downloaded from GitHub, I'm using Xcode 8.1 + swift 3. I've created a pod file as follow

```
target 'sqliteProject' do
  use_frameworks!

 pod ‘SQLite.swift’

end
```

Now, I'm facing following error:

> @import Foundation;
>
> #import "sqlite3.h" // error->...SQLite-Bridging.h:27:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'SQLite.SQLite_Bridging'
>
> NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
>       typedef NSString * _Nullable (^_SQLiteTokenizerNextCallback)(const char *input, int *inputOffset, int *inputLength);
>       int _SQLiteRegisterTokenizer(sqlite3 *db, const char *module, const char *tokenizer, _Nullable _SQLiteTokenizerNextCallback
>   callback);
>    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
>
> Error is "SQLite-Bridging.h:27:9: Include of non-modular header inside
>   framework module 'SQLite.SQLite_Bridging'"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095002/sqlite-sqlite-bridging-h-not-found-in-sqlite-swift#36541719